# What is "# lines" in svn log

Tags: svn

I'm currently reading into svn .log files and I'm very confused. 
Log for one revision typically looks like this (I messed with the data but kept the structure):

```
r12345 | username | 2015-11-26 14:20:12 +0000 (Thu, 26 Nov 2015) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M file1
   M file2
   M file3

Best commit ever
```

I thought that "1 line" means that overall 1 line of code was changed. But how is that possible if 3 files were modified? What does "# lines" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That are the line numbers from your commit message.

Comment: Is there a limit for characters in one line? Because from what I see it doesn't look like it. For example: it is "5 lines for" 
 "NTHNGHR-304 : Frontier - Default Backups Settings to be ON \n
--------------- \n
instant upload was enabled for all data classes by username.\n
Instant upload only for Contacts and Photos will be ON. \n
"

Comment: I think its for every break/return.